# UICollectionView vertical scroll last item

Tags: uiscrollview, uicollectionview

Hi I have a vertical UICollectionView that works just fine, but the las item is barely visible and you have to pan up the scrollview to fully be able to see it, when you stop panning the item bounces back and you can almost interact with it.

I've tried with the bounces properties in the collection view's properties for scrollview in interface builder, but it's still the same.

Should I have to increase "manually" the scrollview's contentsize in order to let me interact with this item?.

You can barely see in the following screenshot, at the bottom just below 25th July

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess here, but maybe your navigation bar is "pushing" your `UICollectionView` down.
Are you sure the frame of the `UICollectionView` is right? Maybe it is extended off screen.

Comment: You are right, I embedded the viewcontroller inside a uinavigationcontroller and the frame for the collectionview went out of the screen area... thank you!.